# Can't enable my wifi on Lenovo G40-30 laptop

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I've searched for an answer by myself for a very long time but nothing helped me.
I can't turn my wifi on (although it works perfectly with Windows) and I can't use ethernet for other reasons. I've already tried `rfkill` and "create a shortcut.." but neither of those worked for me.. 
I'm using a Lenovo G40 with Windows 10 as Primary OS and Ubuntu 14.04 as a dual boot.

For both commands.. (`ifconfig` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` ) ..the output  was:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4026]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Here's the output for `rfkill list`

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

3: hci0: Bluetooth

    Soft blocked: no

    Hard blocked: no
```

for  sudo dmidecode | grep "System Information" -A8

```
 System Information
        Manufacturer: LENOVO
        Product Name: 80FY
        Version: Lenovo G40-30

        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        Family: IDEAPAD
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: try an `ifconfig` and paste the output in your question Along with Pilot6's request

Comment: `ifconfig` is without space. Please also add output of `rfkill list` command.

Comment: Now it is clear what is the problem. Please also add output of `sudo dmidecode | grep "System Information" -A8`

Comment: So my answer should fix your issue.

Comment: Hi Pilot6, I've tried your solutions above but it doesn't work for my laptop. When running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` I got:

`02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142
 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)`

`  Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0621]`

`  Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge`

It looks that the hardware and kernel driver is different.

So any advices to enable wifi on my machine?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no other connection to internet, you can temporarily enable wifi by

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

To make it permanent run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/ideapad-laptop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ideapad-laptop-dkms
```

This will install `ideapad_laptop` with my patch for this laptop. The patch has been accepted upstream but did not reach all Ubuntu kernels.

Comment: well,  the modprobe line worked the wifi is on.
but i couldn't install the ideapad-laptop-dkms..

it says "Media change: please insert the disc labeled             
 'Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter"

Comment: Go to System Settings -> Software & Updates and uncheck the disk as a software source there.